# Error when I use balance command and user is not in the database

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I am writing multifunctional discord bot. I have an issue with economy. I want to make system: when user uses balance command, code should check if user is in database or not.
In my case (without system): If user is in database, all is ok. But if user is not in the database, I see error.
Code of command:

```
@bot.command()
async def баланс(ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
    if member:
        aut = member
    else:
        aut = ctx.author
    
    with open("servers.json", "r") as f:
        data = json.load(f)
    if str(ctx.message.guild.id) in data:
        la = data[str(ctx.message.guild.id)]['oth']['lang']
        emoji = data[str(ctx.message.guild.id)]['eco']['eco_emoji']
        money = data[str(ctx.message.guild.id)]['eco']['users'][str(aut.id)]['money']
        bank = data[str(ctx.message.guild.id)]['eco']['users'][str(aut.id)]['bank']

        if la == 'ru':
             emb = discord.Embed(title=f'Информация о пользователе {aut.name}\n\n', description=f'Баланс: {money} {emoji}\nЛежит в банке: {bank} {emoji}', color=discord.Color.purple())
             emb.set_thumbnail(url=aut.avatar_url) 
             emb.set_footer(text = f'Вызвал {aut.name}', icon_url = aut.avatar_url)
             await ctx.send(embed=emb) 
    else:
        await ctx.send('Please, setup the bot. Command: `.setup`\n\nПожалуйста, установите бота. Команда: `.setup`')
```

Json file:

```
{
    "1028325591570714697": {
        "cd": {
            "ban": 60,
            "casino": 10,
            "fifty": 10,
            "mute": 10,
            "rob": 3600,
            "unban": 60,
            "unmute": 10,
            "unwarn": 10,
            "warn": 10,
            "work": 3600
        },
        "eco": {
            "eco_emoji": ":coin:",
            "shop": {
                "id": {
                    "cost": 100,
                    "name": "",
                    "role_id": ""
                }
            },
            "users": {
                "459007192276795393": {
                    "bank": 10,
                    "inv": {},
                    "money": 316
                },
                "975416507683205171": {
                    "bank": 0,
                    "inv": {},
                    "money": 261
                }
            }
        },
        "oth": {
            "lang": "ru"
        },
        "pay": {
            "chat": "false",
            "extra": "false",
            "logs": "false",
            "salary": "false",
            "voice": "false"
        },
        "roles": {
            "muterole": "None"
        }
    }
}
```

Error if user is not in database:

```
Command raised an exception: KeyError: '988839445392408616'
```

P.S. `988839445392408616` is user ID which balance I am checking.
How can I make system that will check if user is in database or not without errors?
Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

I highly suggest you use a SQL database if you want your bot to run faster, if you are making this bot for only your server with not many users than you can still use a JSON database. DM me on discord if you want more advice or want me to make the code better. RobertK#6151

```
@bot.command()
async def баланс(ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
    if member:
        aut = member
    else:
        aut = ctx.author

    with open("servers.json", "r") as f:
        data = json.load(f)
    if str(ctx.message.guild.id) in data:

        """ CHECK IF USER IS NOT IN DATABASE AND ADD USER TO DATABASE WITH DEFAULT BALANCES """
        if not str(aut.id) in data[str(ctx.message.guild.id)]['eco']['users']:
            data[str(ctx.message.guild.id)]['eco']['users'][str(aut.id)]['money'] = 0  # EDIT DEFAULT MONEY
            data[str(ctx.message.guild.id)]['eco']['users'][str(aut.id)]['bank'] = 0  # EDIT DEFAULT BANK
            data[str(ctx.message.guild.id)]['eco']['users'][str(aut.id)]['inv'] = {}  # EDIT DEFAULT INV
            await ctx.send('You are not in the economy database. Account added')

        la = data[str(ctx.message.guild.id)]['oth']['lang']
        emoji = data[str(ctx.message.guild.id)]['eco']['eco_emoji']
        money = data[str(ctx.message.guild.id)]['eco']['users'][str(aut.id)]['money']
        bank = data[str(ctx.message.guild.id)]['eco']['users'][str(aut.id)]['bank']

        if la == 'ru':
            emb = discord.Embed(title=f'Информация о пользователе {aut.name}\n\n',
                                description=f'Баланс: {money} {emoji}\nЛежит в банке: {bank} {emoji}',
                                color=discord.Color.purple())
            emb.set_thumbnail(url=aut.avatar_url)
            emb.set_footer(text=f'Вызвал {aut.name}', icon_url=aut.avatar_url)
            await ctx.send(embed=emb)
    else:
        await ctx.send('Please, setup the bot. Command: `.setup`\n\nПожалуйста, установите бота. Команда: `.setup`')
```